# Instance variable (Object ,not primitive) caching in Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

Does Java thread caches the Instance variable or will it be shared among all the threads?

```
Class CachedObject{
    MyClass object1 = new MyClass();

    public void changeValue(int i){
        object1.setValue(i);
    }
}
```

Lets suppose, the `changeValue` method will be accessed by multiple threads, then `object1` will be cached in each thread cache or will it be shared?

I know about `synchronized` and if I used `synchronized` on method everything will be ok, but I am specifically asking about the thread caching here. 
I know that local variables are cached in thread cache , but I am confused about Instance variable.
Thanks..

Comment: It can be cached if it is not volatile. volatile guarantees that every write cached object is flushed to main memory.

Comment: so it will be like , the actual object will be on heap and each thread will have their own reference cached for that same object on heap ?

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't cache anything themselves.
But threads read/write in a distinct memory data that it read/write according to the CPU thread model.
And for this reason, synchronization with main memory between threads can be required.
In your case if you create a single instance of `CachedObject` that is shared among multiple threads, the new `object1` state may be not updated/visible for other threads if `setValue()` is implemented in this way :

```
public void setValue(int i){
   this.value = i;
}
```

As it assigns a new value to an `int` field without any synchronization that may so be visible only for the current thread.

But in these ways you would not have the issue :

```
private int volatile value;
public void setValue(int i){      
   this.value = i;
}
```

Or :

```
public void setValue(int i){
   synchronized(this){
      this.value = i;
   }
}
```

Comment: davidxxx.. thanks for the reply . But I know the use of volatile and synchronized and I know I need to use them exactly as you mentioned. But my actual question is about object1 being shared between threads or not. 
will it be like , the actual object will be on heap and each thread will have their own reference cached for that same object on heap ?

Comment: The `CachedObject` instance is stored in the shared/heap memory as this is an  instance field. But in a multithreaded context each Java thread that manipulates this object will have its own copy of its state (field values). So the objects exists at two levels : shared heap, each thread memory.  
That's why without synchronizing the fields accesses the state may be different between the threads.